# Offset WP_Query by negative 1

Tags: wp-query, loop, offsets

I have an event loop and I'm wondering if it's possible to offset the loop by -1, so the prev and next posts of the current post are shown.

**EDIT** - Thanks for your comments, I think I can clarify. When a visitor is on a single-event page, I want to show 4 events at the bottom of the page; the first 2 being past events and the next 2 being upcoming events. I think I need to query all of the events, get the position of the current event result, subtract 2 from that number, and apply that number to the offset.

```
$upcoming_events_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $date_of_page,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: When you have a problem, explain it and ask for a solution. If you invent an odd solution and than ask how can you make that solution work, understing your problem, and so give you a solution, became hard.

Comment: There is a sense in which this question doesn't make sense-- if you are on the first result there is no "-1". Results start at zero. Please [edit] the question so it is more clear what you want.

Comment: Importantly, explain **why**

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your question. exactly

- Do you want next, prev post pagination?

  or
- You want to see next and prev posts titles or other content?

Actually you placed an incorrect value to offset. You have to do something like this.

```
// Initialize where to start the post from, 0 is most recent post
$init_count = 0;

// Get the current page integer
$page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// And the simple formula for offset is this
$offset = ( $page - 1 ) * $init_count;

//Now you should use your query like this:

<?php $upcoming_events_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'number'     =>  $init_count,
    'page'       =>  $page,
    'offset'     =>  $offset,
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $date_of_page,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
      ))
    );
```

And by placing this code after end of the loop, will show your next and previous post.

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li id="previous-posts">
        <?php previous_posts_link( '<< Previous Posts', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </li>
    <li id="next-posts">
        <?php next_posts_link( 'Next Posts >>', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```